# What must I add to this code to meet very detailed requirements about a turn based game?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The game starts by initializing Heroes. Heroes have 4 properties: strength, agility, stamina and health. By default, Health is set to 50 and  stamina is set to 25, but strength and agility must be initialized by rolling one 12 sided die, one 10 sided die, and one 8 sided die. I am having trouble assigning the highest value to strength and setting agility to the sum of the other two values.

A round should consist of each player selecting a move and calculating the resulting damage. Each player must select a move for their hero (attack or defend). Each move requires stamina so if the hero cannot afford the stamina cost, it must rest.

Move details:
Attacking and resting provide no defense so if you are attacked in these states, you receive full damage.
Resting adds health, which mitigates damage, but it is not the same as blocking
Blocking provides defense so if a hero is attacked when blocking, damages could be averted.
If the block value is greater than or equal to the attack value, the attack is dodged.
Otherwise the difference between the attack and the block is the damage.

Attack - Roll a 20 sided die. The attack value is the strength plus the roll. If the Hero cannot meet the stamina cost (6), it must rest and the attack value is zero.
Defend - Roll a 20 sided die. The defend value is the agility plus the die roll. If the Hero cannot meet the stamina cost (4), it must rest and the attack value is zero
Rest - When a player tries to attack/defend but is out of stamina, roll a 6 sided, an 8 sided die, and a 10 sided die. Add the highest value to health. Add the sum of the other two to stamina. No stamina cost here.

End goal is to write a class to test everything:
Create a new BattleManager, Use the BattleManager to setup 2 new Heroes. Print the stats of each hero. Call the round method using the heroes as input parameters. Print the stats of each hero, Call the round method using the heroes as input parameters. Print the stats of each hero. Compare the health of the two heroes. Print the name of the hero with the most health and declare them the winner.

```
public class Hero 
{
 private String name;
 private int health;
 private int strength;
 private int agility;
 private int stamina;
 Die die1;
 Die die2;
 Die die3;

public Hero(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.health = 50;
    this.stamina = 25;
    this.strength = 5;
    this.agility = 5;
}

public void setName(String Name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public void setHealth(int health) 
{
    this.health = health;
}

public int getHealth() 
{
    return health;
}

public void setStrength(int strength) 
{
    this.strength = strength;
}

public int getStrength() 
{
    return strength;
}

public void setAgility(int agility) 
{
    this.agility = agility;
}

public int getAgility() 
{
    return agility;
}

public void setStamina(int stamina) 
{
    this.stamina = stamina;
}

public int getStamina() 
{
    return stamina;
}

public int addHealth() 
{
    if(health < 45 || health >= 0) 
    {
        health = health + 5;
    }
    return health;
}

public int removeHealth() 
{
    if(health <= 50 || health >= 5) 
    {
        health = health - 5;
    }
    return health;
}

public int addStamina() 
{
    if(stamina <= 20 || stamina >= 0) 
    {
        stamina = stamina + 5;
    }
return stamina;
}

public int removeStamina() 
{
    if(stamina <= 25 || stamina >= 5) 
    {
        stamina = stamina - 5;
    }
return stamina;
}

private void rest() 
{
    health = health + addHealth();
    stamina = stamina + addStamina();
}

public int attack(int damage) 
{
    die1 = new Die(20);
    die1.roll();

    if(stamina <= 5) 
    {
        rest();
    }
    else 
    {
        damage = strength + die1.getValue();
        stamina = stamina - 6;
    }
    return damage;
}

public int defend(int block) 
{
    die1 = new Die(20);
    die1.roll();

    if(stamina <= 3) 
    {
        rest();
    }

    if(die1.getValue() <= 6) 
    {
        block = getAgility() + (die1.getValue() * 2);
    }
    else 
    {
        block = getAgility() + (die1.getValue());
    }
    stamina = stamina - 4;
    return block;
}

public void printStats() 
{
    System.out.println("Thy hero's name is: " + getName());
    System.out.println("Thy strengh is: " + getStrength());
    System.out.println("Thy agility is: " + getAgility());
    System.out.println("Thy stamina is: " + getStamina());
    System.out.println("Thy health is: " + getHealth());
}
}
```

Next Class, it needs to be updated to include: setupHero - Takes a string, the name of the hero, as a parameter. The method uses the initialization instructions above (in hero class) to create and initialize a hero object. The method returns the hero object that was created. 
round - takes two hero objects, returns void. Allows user to select moves, performs the moves, and applies damage. Print any info you would like upon completion.
You may include any other private methods you like which would assist the code.

```
    public class Battle_Manager
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     Hero hA = new Hero("Ayy");
     Hero hB = new Hero("Bee");

    Die die1 = new Die(12);
    Die die2 = new Die(8);
    Die die3 = new Die(6);

    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
    die3.roll();

    hA.printStats();
    hB.printStats();
}   
}
```

Last Class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die 
{
private int sides;
private int dieValue;

 public void roll() 
{
    Random r = new Random();
    dieValue = (r.nextInt(sides) + 1);
}

public int getSides() 
{
    return sides;
}

public void setSides(int sides) 
{
    this.sides = sides;
}

public Die() 
{
    sides = 1;
    dieValue = 1;
}

public Die (int sides) 
{
    sides = 1;
    dieValue = 1;

    if(sides >= 0) 
    {
        this.sides = sides;
    }
}

public int getValue() 
{
    int value = dieValue;
    return value;
}
}
```

I understand my code needs a scanner, and possibly a loop, to fight the multiple rounds needed to declare the winner. How would I go about fulfilling all the these rules for the code? I have done the very basics but prompting the user for input is difficult for me. Any help would be great but the more detailed the better.

Comment: "prompting the user for input is difficult for me." but imagine how satisfying it will be when you get it done, and through your own research!

Comment: I understand that would be the optimal route but I am very pressed for time. I see most are viewing this wall of text and assuming I am asking them to do an entire project but I think I am close to done with what I already have. Besides researching user prompts what else should I look up regarding this code?

Comment: I suggest that you read up just a little bit on game design, also look at the answers for this
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/how-should-i-write-a-main-game-loop

Comment: Break the problem down into manageable pieces. This is ALWAYS the start if feeling overwhelmed. Write a test program of about 15 lines to work on the input -- just prompt for input, parse it into pieces, and then print out the pieces. Work until satisfied. It should take you 10 or 15 minutes. Then incorporate what you learned into your larger program. Do that with your other problems. Programming for real is a very very iterative process, and sometimes you write little side programs to figure out how to make something work. Even after 40 years I still do that to work something out.